# How can we test a web application in different language(not english) using selenium webdriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I need to test my site in different language ex. German, but not english. so any ideas of

what would be the best solution in java using selenium webdriver.

Comment: You mean you want the output to be displayed in german?

Comment: I can't see any reason why it would be any different testing a site in another language. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/

Answer (score 0):

We do localization testing using a generalized locale Key (String "XXX")to show everything is localized
Selenium WebDriver in verifying all Fields,Menus and Tabs are localised with the String/Locale key.

That way any translated locale key for any language will work.

Usually the developers do the unique locale key generation / magic.